# How send JavaScript or jquery commands on webview tasker elements?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, tasker

1. I created a scene and webview1 element with:

   - mode: url
   - source: www.google.com
2. created a task to show scene
3. Now, I want to create a JavaScript task to send to the Webview:

   - $("#q").val("Chuck Norris");
   - $("button#search").click();

PS: I don't want to just execute Javascript, I want to execute it in the opened Webview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not really understand what would possibly be the point of creating webview scenes and acting on them, when what you need can be achieved "silently". You can query webpages and traverse their DOM structure without even viewing.

Tasker does support JavaScript and loading external libraries. Have a look here for more detailed explanation: tasker.wikidot.com/userguide-en:javascript

Alternatively, you can give SL4A a go: code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Have you tried adding an action (either Javascript or SL4A) to the Page Loaded event on WebView properties?

// edit

@fredericoallan

What you need to do/use is to play with `HTTP GET`and `HTTP POST` for sending headers and handling sessions (I do recommend tasker plugin: [RESTask](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freehaha.restask) for that as it allows sending headers). But first things first.

### prerequisities

To be able to send headers and set session, you need to find out what headers and cookies are being sent when you open the page and/or click `login` button. To see that (if you're using chrome) you can use chrome's built in developer tools. Just right click somewhere on the page and select "inspect element".
In the window that'll appear, go to tab "network"

#### session

Just refresh the page and observe the `network` tab. First request on the list should be `GET` method and type `text/html`. Click it. Select `headers` tab in the right pane. You should now notice, that our session ID is being stored in a cookie under `PHPSESSID`. We're gonna need that information later

#### headers

To be able to log in, you need to have an open session, otherwise server will deny you access.
We've checked how and where session key is stored, so we can have a look at log-in headers (we need to know how your username and passord are being sent to the server).

Having developer tools still open, click `login` button. Content of the `network` tab should have changed. What is interesting for us, is the first request sent ( `index.php?act=login`, method `POST`, type `text/html`). When clicked, we should see things like remote address, request URL, request method and little bit down below `Form Data` containing username, password, submit attributes.

### building Tasker's task

Now, having gathered all that information, we can proceed to building a task, that will log us in.

1. create HTTP GET action (with no additional parameters/headers) pointing to `redmine.demo.org`. In a server response you'll receive the HTML markup, headers and cookie to be set.
2. extract %sessionID from the cookie (using variable search and replace or variable section)
3. create HTTP POST action pointing to `https://www.untergrund.net/index.php?act=loginpost` with a header: `Cookie=%sessionID` and parameters: `username=%userid`, `password=%pass`, `PHPSESSID=%sessionID`

you are now logged in. Response received will contain page that is diplayed upon login.

### code example

```
HTTP loggin in (119)
A1: RESTask [ Configuration:REST call Package:com.freehaha.restask Name:RESTask Timeout (Seconds):30 ] 
A2: Test Variable [ Type:Length Data:%rthdr_set_cookie Store Result In:%sesslen ] 
A3: Variable Section [ Name:%rthdr_set_cookie From:1 Length:%sesslen-8 Adapt To Fit:Off Store Result In:%sessionID ] 
A4: RESTask [ Configuration:REST call Package:com.freehaha.restask Name:RESTask Timeout (Seconds):30 ]
```

Comment: I'll give you an example:
- enter redmine.demo.org
- click login
- fill username and password
- Click the Login button

i want automate somes job operations in my job. 

@Tomaski You could CREATE a example task doind that? Tks

Comment: @fredericoallan - in fact I have created a very similar profile for myself. I'll share some more details in another answer, as this is too short ;)